# UV Unwrap/UV Skinning: Blender vs. 3DS Max

Tags: uv

I'm starting to get annoyed by the lack of information on this subject...

Anyway, this is kinda-sorta a repeat of a previous question that was belittled into non-existence. I want to know if 'UV mapping' in Blender is *exactly the same* as it is in 3DS Max, and if it isn't, then *how and where is it different?*

Comment: Every 3D software have similar and different methods for UV mapping, I don't think this question is very useful, try to ask something more specific.

Comment: I'm being as specific as I can! The blender manual has noting on UV mapping and I want to know if it can be done in Blender, or if I have to port it over to 3DS Max before I can skin it!!! Also, @Ray Mairlot: I'll accept your edit. It's a simple yes or no, here's how it's false question!!!!! Why can't you guys think like me, is it because of my Asperger's or something?

Comment: http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/uv/unwrapping.html

Comment: Please consider viewing a useful video tutorial on [Blender UV Mapping] on a video site. Youtube is one example.  This BSE site is part of the community documentation.  Blender documentation comes from many places at this moment and will probably remain that way for the next few years or more.  You will be disappointed if you expect all the good documentation to come from Blender.org.  Blender is has many features and is challenging.

Comment: @Nefer007 Your question is too broad, this site is for answers to specific questions (specific doesn't mean clear - it means for single problems). This site is not to do your research for you! There is no lack of information, there is lack of your effort to find any (videos for uv mapping everywhere, blender manual, etc.). Also please stop shouting and don't use capslock unless you are a kid - no one owns you any answers. Be kind and you will get kind response.

Comment: arrrrrrrrrrrg... that's EXACTLY the point! I want someone to be keeping everything up-to-date, removing missing file links and things like that!  http://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/skinning/objects.html is a dead page, http://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/physics/material.html is a dead page, the demos don't exist, there aren't any walkthroughs, it's shoddy work and it's confusing me!

Comment: UV unwrapping is doing essentially the same thing no matter what software you are using, see [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23174/5705) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Nefer007 You are totally right that blender documentation is in terrible shape and should be fixed and be updated. If it was payed software you would be right to be angry and demand a fix. But this is opensource so it's kinda expected - nobody has time for it. If you want to invest your time to keep the documentation up to date and filled with good info I think blenderfoundation will welcome you with open arms. With paid software you get the service though.

Comment: @Nefer007  "Someone" = you and me. I've been contributing to the docs where I can, but more people are always needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in "exactly the same" you are talking about the ***process*** of unwrapping then **no**, every software you use will do it slightly differently; if, however, you mean the ***result*** of unwrapping an object, then (as far as I know and practically speaking) **yes**.

So I will attempt to answer your question in two parts:

## Process:

The main difference in the process of UV unwrapping between 3ds Max and Blender is that in Max, unwrapping is done within a modifier; whereas in Blender it is done at the base mesh level in edit mode.

This is the only main difference I can think of at the moment.  Obviously there will be many other minor differences.  But there really isn't much that either software can do that the other can't.  It is mostly determined by ease of use and personal preference.

---

## Result:

As I mentioned above, the result of unwrapping an object is basically the same as in 3ds Max.  I.E. every vertex on the model is assigned a [UV coordinate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/what-methods-can-be-used-to-place-a-texture-onto-an-object/23174#23174) and the coordinates are interpolated between them across the faces.