# UV map not applying on Object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I am trying to build my own spaceship according to the spaceship tutorial created by BlenderGuru.

However, there' s a problem with the UV map I have created for the spaceship.
[image: model, UVs, material nodes]

As you can see, I have already added the image to the node editor and connected it to a displacement socket and added the image to the UV image editor.

I am clueless what might cause the problem. Maybe you could help me to solve this problem.
Here' s an additional image of the UV map I've created for the spaceship.
[image: texture map]

Here is the .blend file:
[image]

Comment: Try to enable "keep UV and edit mode mesh in sinc" and select the areas on the mesh which you want to have Displacement map on them, then make sure they are fine with the UV Texture(layout)

Comment: In the image I added, the UV map is correctly placed over the object. :S

Comment: Did you tried to add Displacement through the Displacement *Modifier* ?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn' t give me the look like there was in the video. By the way, I am sure he didn't use displacement modifier in the video. It must be done some other way. I must have missed something important..

The video is here: youtube.com/watch?t=1811&v=06A_l95vJWw. Watch it from the 30th minute.

Comment: I think I know, did you subdivide the mesh? displace only works on geometry that is there, no vertex to move = looks like it does not do anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Duplicated Material output node

Even though it seems to be one, if you try to grab it and move it slightly you should discover that there's another one just behind it.

[image]
[image]

When you have multiple material output, Blender set as **active** the last selected of them. As in your setup Shader/Surface and Displacement are in different output node, you cannot see both effect at the same time.

Delete one material output node and plug the cables in the other.

[image]

Comment: Oh. Damn. I feel so ashamed now. I didn't know the problem is caused by this.. 

I truly thank you all for trying to help me and Carlo, thanks for your solution. (still feeling so bad that the problem had so easy solution)..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a *UV map* node and plugging it into the image texture's *vector* input.

[image]

For more on texture coordinates see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23174/5705).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but as weird as it seems, it doesn' t work for some reason..

I am really confused now. What might have caused the problem for me...

Comment: @TheLast_BlenderBender  Well, beyond this it's really hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the actual file.

Comment: I added the file under the comments of my question.

Answer (score -1):

In the texture tab, do you have UV mode selected?

for nodes you will need to use the output from the object
node UV

Comment: I sincerely apologize, but I didn' t understand your solution...

Comment: Using uvs with non node materials is just as easy as selecting Uv in the mapping section.

Comment: using Uv in the node layout means you need to start with a node(geometry? or object?) to get the uv cordinates to begin your node graph, I dont remember the name of the node,

Comment: No. apparently it doesn' t change anything, Igor

Comment: post a picture of your full node graph?

Comment: Hmmm.. That' s weird.. In the BlenderGuru tutorial he just connects it to the displacement socket.
The video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1811&v=06A_l95vJWw.
Watch it from the 30th minute.

Comment: The node graph is here: http://gyazo.com/4f82b4ff6831fe76f0108fa05b7c300e

Comment: see the input vector? on the node connected to displacement? try connecing Uv output from the Geometry node to that.

Comment: also, is the node material selected for the object in materials tab?

Comment: Hmmm.. Can' t find a way to a connect it to geometry node..
And yes. The material is applied to the object.

Comment: just add the geometry node, drag from UV to Vector?

Comment: also, a displacement map is usually baked, I am not sure what that UV map would do?

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure, but it doesn' t work..

Comment: I just baked a displacement map, and set it up as a modifier, and it's not behaving correctly.

Comment: ok, I can get a modifier working using a uv map,
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37438

Comment: I will try using nodes

Comment: @BluePrintRandom It sounds like your answer is for BI, but I think the OP here is using Cycles.

Comment: yeah I was just testing what I know, before I tried to apply the same maps,
to nodes.