# Model turns Brown instead of a Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube but my model (and many others') turn brown when rendering (cycles render) instead of a wood texture. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Interestingly, the text does have the texture:

[image]

EDIT Starts now: Here's the shader nodes:

[image]

And here's the .blend file!

[image]

I think I found the problem: instead of the texture - the same colour as the rendered model in the 'Render Layers' node, how do I fix this? This also happened after I started added the animation.

[image]

Comment: Try selecting your model and applying it's scale (ctrl-A). It might be the proper wood texture, but it's scaled up so big that you can't see the details.

Comment: Is your box UV mapped?

Comment: I did use compositing. I edited the shader nodes so there was a connection from Colour in Image Texture to Displacement in Material Output. This was supposed to add some 'depth' to the texture. By the way, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFmN7eTNfNw) is the tutorial video.

Comment: @MarineBiologist What type of [mapping coordinates](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23174/5705) are you using?  It looks like you don't have any.

Comment: @PGmath I used a material to texture it. In the 'color' section, I put 'Image Texture' and loaded up the image that I was going to use. There is a reason why are tagged my question as 'cycles'.

Comment: But, as the post I liked above describes, an image texture has to have some type of mapping coordinates that tell Cycles what parts of the texture go where.

Comment: @TLousky I did do 'project from view (bounds)'.

Comment: OK, so now the question is whether your image texture uses this UV map. You can add a screenshot of your material node setup to your question which could help, and/or upload the blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link to your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer is quite simple. All I needed to do is just go to the modifiers tab, scroll down to the 'Explode' section (I used a 'Quick Explode' animation, don't even ask me why it caused such a problem) and uncheck 'Cut Edges'. Thanks for the support and ideas, though, as this wouldn't be here for people who would need it in the future without all of your support.

[image: Explanatory image]

Source:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You didn't UV unwrap your object. I run into this as well. Just go into Edit Mode, select everything and hit 'U' to unwrap. That should fix everything.

Comment: Does this take into account that I'm using a quick explode animation?