# Image textures on planes are distorted

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I added a texture to a plane.
When rendered, the texture on the plane is all distorted.

[image: Textures on the planes are weird.]
I'd like for the texture to fit nicely on the plane.

In case I haven't submitted enough information (i.e. properties on the texture or plane), please comment, and I'll edit my post right away.

Comment: how did you assign this textures , did you unwrap the objects?

Comment: @Chebhou, I don't quite know what you mean by that (I am new to Blender). I had the plane selected, went to the "Texture" inspector, made the type "Image or Movie" right above the "Preview" sub-inspector, and set the image in the "Image" sub-inspector.

Comment: you have added the texture but you need tell blender how to position it on the object , and there are many ways for that

Comment: check this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/what-methods-can-be-used-to-place-a-texture-onto-an-object/23174#23174

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that rather than using UV coordinate mapping, use generated.

[image: Before]

to

[image: After]