# Texture Coordinate vs Geometry Node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

When working with generated texture coordinates I see sometimes the Texture Coordinate (generated) and sometimes the Geometry (Position) node used. What is exactly the difference ?

Comment: Geometry position is almost certainly the (X,Y,Z) coordinate of the surface (or interior) point that is to be coloured/textured etc. as part of the render.  Texture Coordinate defines what is to be used for the (U,V) coordinate used to lookup a position on the UV Map and use the pixel information found at that point as the source for the rendered pixel (or the onward journey through node graph).

[link](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/input.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *Generated* and *Position* outputs each represent coordinate systems.  These are often used as [texture coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/what-methods-can-be-used-to-place-a-texture-onto-an-object/23174#23174) for procedural textures since they are 3-dimensional, though they can be useful for other effects as well.

---

### Generated Texture Coordinates

*Generated* coordinates are defined by the bounding box of an object, and are unique to each object.

Generated texture coordinates give the bounding-box-space position across the mesh.  The bottom, left, front of the bounding box is the origin (coordinates `[0, 0, 0]`), and the top, right, back of the bounding box is `[1, 1, 1]`.

[image]

I use generated coordinates when I need the texturing to transform, particularly rotate, with the object.  However when the bounding box is significantly non-cuboidal generated textures will stretch and distort the texturing.  In these cases you may need to manually "un-stretch" the texture with a *mapping* node, or use *Position* coordinates.

Generated coordinates can also be useful for non-texturing methods, like creating gradients or other more advanced techniques.

---

### Position Coordinates

The *Geometry* > *Position* output gives the position in world-space across the object.  The origin (`[0, 0, 0]`) is the *world* origin and all other points are simply their respective position *in Blender Units* relative to the origin.

[image]

I like to use Position coordinates to keep uniform texture scaling across with a material assigned to multiple objects with different sized bounding boxes.  Using Position coordinates also prevents distorted stretching on objects with significantly non-cuboidal bounding boxes.

Comment: I would say it does not matter too much in practical situations to use the one or the other. Or are there situations that it matters which node you use ?

Comment: @JanScherders  See edit.