# Generated texture coordinates vs Unwrapped texture coordinates

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

If you want to map an equirectangular image texture to a sphere - like a map of the earth to a sphere - is there any necessity to use an UV map ? Or can I simply use the generated texture coordinates ? In general, when do you choose for UV unwrapping and when to use generated texture coordinates ?

I don't think this question is a duplicate with [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere) question because these answers all start with the uv unwrapping method and I want to know if UV unwrapping or generated texture coordinates works best for my specific question.
And I also would like to learn some general guidelines when choosing uv unwrapped vs generated texture coordinates

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection

Comment: I still don't agree that this question is a duplicate. I don't ask what is the best way to unwrap a sphere but I ask what is the best way to map an image texture to a sphere ... Please explain why my question is a duplicate

Comment: I agree that this is most certainly *not* a dupe.  This question merely uses a sphere as an incidental example and is not asking about the best way to unwrap a sphere; rather about pros and cons and use cases of generated vs. UV coords.

Comment: @JanScherders Since you've asked how texturing a sphere, it's a dupe (IMO). When you really think about it there must be a reason why the answers starting with uv unwrapping, BTW: answers have nothing to do with questions. If the answers of the found questions doesn't solve your issue why not simply write: "Based on this question i'd like to know..." instead of "This is not a dupe" - this is less offensive and better practice (IMO). Also duplicates are not bad, they are helping future visitos to find the correct answer. Anyway, don't take it personal.

Comment: @poor Thanks for your feedback. I still have to get used to the idea that duplicates are not bad. Everytime when someone tells me I added a duplicate I feel like I have done something wrong. And I will certainly try to improve my language. Thanks, poor !!

Comment: @JanScherders  Though I still didn't agree that this was a dupe, poor is right that dupes aren't bad at all, especially considering that SE's search functionality leaves a *lot* to be desired.  (Ironically missing link to meta post I couldn't find about how dupes aren't bad.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UV Unwrapping

The one major benefit of UV unwrapping an object is that it gives you exact control over the texture placement.  Usually you would unwrap geometrically complex objects, or objects which you would like to do texture painting or add decals to.

However, UV mapping has two major pitfalls.

- **Seams.**  By unwrapping an object you are basically cutting it up with seams and flattening it out to place a 2D texture on it.  The obvious problem is that these seams create undesirable "cuts" in the texturing.  So care must be taken to place seams where they are least visible.
- **Distortion.**  Due to the nature of UV unwrapping, by cutting a 3D object up and plastering it flat there will be some distortion of the geometry.  If done well this can be minimized fairly well, but that often requires more seams.  So when UV unwrapping an object you need to find a balance between more seams and more distortion.

Usually the benefit of having complete control over the final output (which is often absolutely necessary for complex models and custom texturing) outweighs these cons.  In such cases the above problems can usually be sufficiently mitigated.

---

### Generated Coordinates

The key to [generated coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45149/5705) is that they are 3-dimensional.  This is both their biggest advantage and disadvantage.  Being 3-dimensional makes them perfect for procedural textures and [voxels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) (though position coordinates work just peachy too).  However, being 3-dimensional also means it is often tough and/or not ideal to use generated coordinates with 2-D image textures.

There are a few ways of using generated coordinates for 2-D textures, through [using different mapping projections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45205/5705) or some more advanced vector wrangling.

Answer (score 4):

**Each situation** really determines what you should do.

---

### *In general*

- Using **generated** coordinates gives you *less* control, but is *easier*.
- Using **UV's** is more *precise*, but *harder*, especially on complex meshes.

---

*Now*, I will use an **example** scene, to show some of the differences.

In *this* example, we will use:

1. Sphere one uses generated texture coordinates
2. Sphere two uses **sphere projection**, to create a *UV map*.

*In this circumstance*, I like the results of **sphere 1** better than that of sphere 2.

[image]

When using *generated* texture coordinates, **keep in mind** what mode of *texture projection* you are using. I have a *sphere*, so I am using **sphere projection**. For other objects with *complex meshes* that you *do not want to unwrap*, **box projection** is usually a good option.

When looking at the **UV map** that was created through *sphere projection* on *sphere two*, you may notice that the unwrap is **not** *perfect*, and that is one of the advantages of using **generated** texture coordinates.

---

Also, **remember** that using *UV* or *generated* texture coordinates **are not** the *only* options. Using *object* coordinates can come in useful when you want the texture's projection to **change** *based on the **position*** of the object, such as when creating roof tiles. You may use a cracked texture, and want the cracks to be in a *different* place **per tile**.

---

So **when deciding**, just think about what your *goals* are, and what the easiest way to get there is. *In the earth model case*, I would use **generated** coordinates with **sphere** texture projection.