# materials not being rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

all my materials applied to my model is not being rendered out when i go in for the final render. as shown here. PS look closely its not just a black bachground[image: image shows no material or lighting from lights]

the bottom picture is what is suppposed to be rendered
[image]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: pretty sure you have the same problem as I answered [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50306/2217)