# White material shows up as gray regardless of lighting

Tags: rendering, materials, rigid-body-simulation

i have just finished Blender Guru's [rigid body simulation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY&list=PL65425E98E2E7B9F0) and was looking to texture and render it, but i have encountered an issue with adding a white material and having it show up as an adequate shade.

So far i have tried:
Changing the brightness of the light
Changing the emission of the material
Changing the render engine (To Cycles)
Changing the color of the blender background
Exporting the rigid body sim to keyframes and changing the material

Some of these work, but do not give me the result i am looking for. The two files attached below show what i am up to (rigid body sim) and what i am aiming for (default). Essentially i can make a new blender file and add a plain with the default material and have it work, but when adding the default material in the rigid body sim, it looks very dissimilar.

I feel like  [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50306/why-are-the-materials-of-my-objects-not-rendering/50317#50317) post is vaguely relevant, but (i thought) material override is removed in blender 2.8.

Files:
Simple blender file with the color that i am looking for:  [Default.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18ojgGaGLK__TWmOMdBdP5eobGOx1ZR18) 
The file that i am trying to fix:  [Rigid body sim.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cYzFQb1m76lewbFQk0Xy6OJZbkJdDEMU)

Thanks!

Comment: Material override was not removed. It is in the view layer section>Override. Read [2.8 is it possible to assign override a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at both files and the only difference really is that you got rid of the camera and light in the wrecking ball file.

If that is the only thing you want to change:

1. Load the "rigid body sim.blend" file.
2. Switch the render engine to cycles to get the same result and switch to render view!
3. Go in the file menu and select "Append..."
4. Find and double click the "default.blend" file to open up it's content to chose from.
5. Go in the "Objects" folder and select "Camera" and "Light"
6. Confirm to load.
7. In the scene the two new objects are hidden inside the cubes, so select them and scale them (yes scale, will only scale them in regard of position from world center) far enough to have a good view. Check by switching to the camera view.
8. Now select the light and increase it's Power from 1000 to something like 10000+..
9. Go from there and you should be fine.

Here the visual aid/explanation:

[image]

Comment: @Mortbros I removed the material assignment part i answered with first, as it seemed to not really belong here. Should you need some more info regarding that, please adjust the question to include colors and i can add it back. Else it's better to restrict the answer to one problem at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the easy to follow answer!