# Geometry node as input for Fresnel node

Tags: texturing

If I use the Geometry node as an input for Fresnel, which attribute of the Geometry node do I connect to the Fresnel node (and why) ? Below an image of the node tree that I am building

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? That will determine what to plug and how to plug it! If you are trying to build a PBR Fresnel then first watch Cynicat's videos on Youtube, it's a nice introduction.

Comment: I have a sun shining on a sphere (planet earth) and want to have realistic reflections and I thought that i can do that best with connecting the Geometry Node to the Fresnel node and that connecting to a mix node. I will edit my question and add an image of the node tree

Comment: Why are you using Position as Mapping coordinates? That results in your texture not moving with your object.. Everything else is OK. You don't have to put anything into the Fresnel Normal input, Blender will use the object's normals by default.

Comment: @Jerryno In this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45199/generated-texture-coordinates-vs-unwrapped-texture-coordinates?noredirect=1#comment76378_45199 I asked how best to map my image textures to a sphere. I also asked this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45148/texture-coordinate-vs-geometry-node/45149?noredirect=1#comment76202_45149 That is why I use the Position for mapping coordinates. Why is my texture not moving with my object ?

Comment: @Jerryno ... so the connection between the Geometry node and Fresnel node is not necessary because Blender will use the normals by default ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't mind you explaining a few things in chat :)

Comment: Yes the connection is not necessary blender will use normals by default. I don't think you understand how mapping vectors work, you don't want to use the position output but generated texture coordinates. There should be multiple questions and answers on this site discussing this in detail.

Comment: I asked a couple of days a question about Geometry and Texture Coordinates but perhaps I still don't understand it ... It was my understanding that a Geometry node can be used for generated texture coordinates ....

Comment: @PGmath could you perhaps shed some light on the above issue of (in)correctly using Position for generated texture coordinates ?

Comment: It is well documented here how the outputs differ: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45149/7777. What you don't understand is what effect will those mappings have on a texture.

Comment: @Jerryno I hope you don't mind that I come back one last time. Do you mean the sentence "I use generated coordinates when I need the texturing to transform, particularly rotate, with the object." ?? Or where do you think I don't understand ?

Comment: Yes, you use generated texture coordinates when you need the texturing to transform with the object. So why you are not using them?

Comment: OK. you mean that when I want to rotate the earth I better use Texture Coordinates ? If that is your point I understand and I will replace the Position by Texture Coordinates. Many thanks for the lesson !!