# How to change scale of a texture through nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I have created a wave texture which I assigned to one face, this is the object rendered:

[image]

This is the node setup:

[image]

I have set the wave type to be "rings", but in the rendered object these rings are stretched out like ovals.

How can I scale the texture in one axis to get circular rings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a Vector Mapping node.  You can control the scale and placement for different axes:

[image]

Or plug it to the scale depending on what kind of effect you are after:

[image]

Comment: Alright! I didn't know I had to use both the texture coordinate and mapping nodes, I just used a texture coordinate on UV and connected it to the texture, so I had to change the UV map by hand, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The stretching you are seeing is because the wave texture uses *Generated* [texture coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work/23174#23174) by default.  Generated coordinates are based on the bounding box of the object.  So if the bounding box is not a cube (which yours isn't), the generated coordinates will be stretched.

You can fix this by using *Position* texture coordinates.  Position coordinates are based on world-space, so they are not affected by the scale and bounding box shape of the object.

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45149/5705) for more on generated vs. position coordinates.