# What is the difference between "Generated" and "Normal" texture coordinates?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, texture-coordinates

I cannot understand from the documentation the difference in the *Texture Coordinate* node (in Shader) between *Generated* and *Normal*, and even the purpose of the *Texture Coordinate* node itself, which I have as the first node.

Comment: you could try daniel kraffts video (on youtube) titled "all material nodes in blender explained"

Comment: Have a look at [this presentation](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0) by Bartek Skorupa on texture coordinates.It is a bit long, but a lot of good information in the talk.

Comment: Skip the Intro [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss - Bartek Skorupa](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=266)

Comment: And 2 English sentences, one for Generated and one for Normal could be given ?

Comment: you can start here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html?highlight=texture%20coordinates

Comment: [Texture Coordinate vs Geometry Node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45148/texture-coordinate-vs-geometry-node) and [how-do-texture-coordinates-work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work/23174#23174)

Comment: The referenced YouTube video by Daniel Krafft might or might not be *[All 80+ Blender material nodes explained in under 30 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQ0qtcSymDI)*

Comment: @Isaiah Haveman: Can you link directly to it (or provide the ID)? Alternatively, confirm.

Comment: Shader nodes start at 07 min 16 secs

Comment: The [manual entry for the Texture Coordinate node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html).

Answer (score 11):

It may help to visualize it this way:

When we render a scene, for each pixel on the camera we project a ray, and if we make contact with the surface of an object, we ask "What is the color that should be reported for this pixel given material properties, lighting, occlusion etc?"

[image: Camera ray being cast at a cube]

This is fairly simple when the material is a solid color, but what about materials that vary?

A procedural material can be thought of as a "field" in the physics sense, it exists and has a value in every position in your scene.  When you map this texture to an object and look at it in the viewport you are displaying the cross section of this field that coincides with the surface of your object.

[image: Voronoi texture displayed on a plane and as a cube volume.]

The Texture Coordinate node merely defines the X,Y,Z coordinate space used to map the texture.  Object coordinates, for example, use Blender's scale setting and set the object's origin as 0,0,0.  Generated coordinates use the object's bounding box as the coordinate space over a range of 0,0,0 to 1,1,1.

[image: Coordinate Spaces visualized ignoring depth]

Normal coordinates are a little strange.  My current understanding is that they are *less* based on position, and more on the rotation of each individual face (more specifically the normal direction).  Maybe someone will expand on how this may be useful for you, my knowledge is limited on this one.

Answer (score 9):

Just to expand a bit on [Allen Simpson's fine answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202472/what-is-the-difference-between-generated-and-normal-texture-coordinates/202490#202490):

[image]

*Generated* coordinates return the *location* of the currently evaluated shading-point, say, **P**, calculated in the 'Generated' texture space, which, whatever the size of the shaded object, measures 0-1 along the sides of its bounding box, with its origin at the minimum. The bounding box is parallel to the object's local axes, (which may be skew to the mesh, if you rotated the mesh in Edit Mode).

(This is a default; the 'Generated' space actually can be scaled and shifted in the *Texture Space* panel of the object's *Data* tab.. but I think that's a bit of a legacy?)

Two of the outputs of the *Texture Coordinate* node, *Normal* and *Reflection*, don't return the location *of* **P**; they return directions *from* **P**: locations on the unit sphere centred on **P**.

*Normal* in the *Texture Coordinate* node returns the vector from **P**, in the direction of the interpolated (after smoothing) normal of the surface, to the tip of the yellow arrow, 1 Blender unit long. It's measured in Object Space: its X,Y and Z components are parallel to the Object's X,Y, and Z.

*Normal* in the *Geometry* node returns the same thing, but in World Space. The *Reflected* output returns the direction of the currently evaluated incoming ray, onward, after reflection from the surface at **P**. It is also measured along axes aligned with the World.

Comment: Excuse me, mister. Could you please help me with this question?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300633/how-does-normal-texture-coordinate-work

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, @IanAmbrose. I think it turns out that (IMO) Nathan has answered it very well, since this request! If his answer doesn't quite do it for you, i'd recommend a diplomatic nudge to clarification, over there :D