# Texture "stretching"

Tags: texturing, uv

New to Blender and my first time using textures. I tried to do a clay-like model but on some parts, the texture is stretching (eyes and legs particularly).

Any idea what I did wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Want to show how the UV map looks like?

Comment: Updated the post with the UV for the head.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the UV map.

The leaf takes a lot of texture UV space but it's fairly small in 3D space. That way it has a lot of details (=compression).
But the eyes get very little texture space and are big in 3D space. So they have only little texture details (=stretching).

A [checkerboard texture can visualize this for you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/unwrap-model-with-uvs-at-proper-size). Ideally, the chess patterns should all be the same size.

You can try to unwrap again with *Smart UV Project* ([What is the difference between Unwrap and Smart uv project?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47052/what-is-the-difference-between-unwrap-and-smart-uv-project)).

Or edit the UV map

- scale down the leaf in the UV editor (hover mouse over an UV island and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select it).
- and try menu: *UV → Minimize Stretch*. The editor will then try to give the eyes more space (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you create a very simple mesh:

[image]

The automatic UV unwrapping will give a very predictable result:

[image]

The mapping can be rotated and scaled so it looks exactly like the mesh (since the mesh is two-dimensional)

[image] [image]

Now, the mesh can be modified to represent a box, without changing the UV:

[image]

You can notice, that the the texture is not wrapping correctly around the edges:

[image]

This is because those edges don't connect on UV map:

[image]

But how do you connect them? You can't - not unless you're willing to warp some of those squares into a different shape:

[image]

And that's how you get stretching using automatic UV unwrapping. You can strategically mark seams to decrease stretching; here I will completely get rid of stretching, by selecting 4 bottom edges and one of vertical edges, right clicking and choosing "mark seam":

[image]

[image]

Final result:

[image]

In your particular case, you want to add seams in the least visible parts like the back and bottom of the head. You may also just add a seam in a visible spot, but fix the texture later, by copying a fragment near one side of the seam on a temporary layer to the other side of the seam, then painting to hide the differences.

Comment: That is very useful. I haven't messed with uv mapping til now.