# Texture on box stretching on the vertical axis

Tags: texturing

I am trying to add eyes on a texture but the texture is stretching on the y axis making the eye very long.

This is the face texture:

[image]

This is the resulting head:

[image]

The texture settings for this face of the cube:

[image]

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong? The dots are being stretched becoming vertical lines on the cube. If I change the Image mappings Extention option to "Cut" from "Repeat" I end up with two spaces on left and right side but the sprite is still stretched on the y axis.

Comment: Try using Object instead of Generated. If that doesn't help, you may need to UV unwrap.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you mean that the texture gets stretched by the vertical axis ? In this case it's stretched by Z axis (which is up in Blender). You can add link with images you share in comments to your question; they will be included into the question's body.

Comment: Thank you for helpful comments, it worked as I made it to Object. If Duane makes his reply in to an answer it can be marked as correct answer.

Comment: @Gatsu I think an answer to that effect would need some supporting explanation about why changing it works. I'm a bit busy at the moment, but I'll post such an answer, when I have the time, unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: I usually say that if you are using an image texture then you will most likely need to set an UV unwrap and line up the texture to the uvs to display correctly on your mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the *Generated* coordinates take the object to have equal size along all three axes, and textures get mapped to between 0 and 1, which can cause stretching or deflating.
The *Object* coordinates take into consideration the object's actual size, and map textures according to that.

With this texture

[image]

I get this with *Generated*

[image]

this with *Object* and *Extension* set to *Repeat*

[image]

and this with *Object* and *Extension* set to *Clip*

[image]

With *Generated* in this case *Clip* or *Repeat* doesn't make a difference, since the image gets stretched across the entire surface either way.
The above examples I believe are the most relevant to your specific case, but for more in-depth explanations of texture coordinates, [this post by PGmath](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work) is definitely good reading. Also [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0) is an excellent lecture by Bartek Skorupa. Mr. Skorupa focuses mainly on Cycles, but the underlying coordinates work the same in Internal, so you shouldn't have a problem with it if you want to stick to Internal.