# Streching near edge on unwrapped mesh

Tags: uv

On the left view (rendered 3D) the material looks stretched and I can't figure out why that is happening, I expect it to work well. It's a fresh project and the plane object has a subdivision modifier applied with adaptive checked.

[image: Example]

Comment: This can be result of Adaptive Subdivision as well, though in this case it would be more apparent

Answer (score 1):

You have probably unwrapped the UV before you made the margin wider. Mesh changes require UV changes accordingly to avoid distortion. Best to avoid unwrapping unless no further changes to the mesh are planned.

Unwrapped the geometry:
[image: initially unwrapped]

Changed the mesh. The UVs are no more correct:
[image: mesh altered]

Corrected UVs:
[image: uv corrected]

Comment: The mesh was unwrapped after all the cuts have been made. The problem actually seems to be with combining UV texture coordinates with procedural textures [(link)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work). Procedural textures work with the geometry texture coordinates.

Comment: It is visible in the screenshot (I have measured the Pixels) that your UVs are not sized accurately. Does the Problem still occur if you match the size of the inner face to its UV exactly?

Comment: The polygons are blue because there is no stretching (there would be some green showing otherwise), but yes, when i move them manually I can correct it. But why do I have to move them manually? The seams look ok, there is not stretching and the mesh was unwrapped after all the cuts and seams were added.

Comment: For the stretching: the color does only take angles into account, not correct aspect ratio or line lengths. Which unwrapping method did you use to generate this UVs?