# I can't control how i paint my mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I have no idea what is going on. I'm trying to add the darker spots to the churro but When i paint directly on the mesh, it just fills out the whole thing even though i'm not using the bucket tool. It has nothing to do with brush size to my knowledge. But if i try to paint on the texture nothing happens to the mesh.
[image: Nothing is happening]

Until it reaches a point when it all suddently gets filled in again even though i haven't filled the entire texture paint yet.

[image: Even so, the color is very weird]

It might have something to do with the weird star shape of the mesh, but i have no idea how to fix it. Here are the blender files if you guys could take a look:

Here is the Churro:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zwN5oTe22kGGo3VxmtgQDtS27g2ioMW8/view?usp=sharing

And here is an eclair that i was trying to do but i faced the exact same problem. It also uses the same star shaped mesh for the dough so that might have something to do with it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VgU99bw-2lxp5JQtjV7y86ykhmlmzbf8/view?usp=sharing,

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi! welcome to Stack Exchange. To me it seems your mesh isn't unwrapped, although your viewport is still set to "view solid" mode. [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work) is a post you may find helpful for understand UV unwraps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mesh is not properly UV unwrapped. Here is what you can do to solve it:

[image]

First select the entire mesh in *Edit Mode* (press <kbd>a</kbd> while in *Edit Mode*), then press <kbd>u</kbd> and click *Smart UV Project* to let Blender automatically unwrap it for you.

[image]

I used the default settings as shown above which worked fine on this project, then press the OK button

[image]

After doing this, I was able to correctly texture paint the model. Hope this helps. If you still have any trouble, there are plenty UV unwrapping tutorials online.